# How to pass an element width as a prop?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to pass the width of a table cell as a prop to a component inside it :

```
 <td bind:clientWidth={cellWidth}>
        <NestedComponent cellWidth={cellWidth} />
  </td>
```

and then in the nested component I'm trying to access it through a lyfecycle method but it logs as undefined

```
<script lang="ts">
import { afterUpdate, onMount } from "svelte";
  export let cellWidth;
  
  let listWidth;
  
  onMount(()=> {
    console.log('cellWidth', cellWidth);
  })

  afterUpdate(() => {
    console.log('cellWidth', cellWidth);
  }) 

</script>
```

however if I render the width inside the component it will show me the width

```
<div>{cellWidth}</div>
```

How can I access that number in the lifecycle method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky case. The order of execution of `onMount` and the initial `afterUpdate` is that children execute before their parent. This makes sense because conceptually each child needs to be mounted before the parent can complete its mount.

In your case, the value of `cellWidth` is only known *after* the *parent* component has mounted, since computation of the width needs the nodes to be present in the DOM. This means you cannot use `onMount` nor the initial `afterUpdate` for this, and it seems that Svelte does not fire another `afterUpdate` when the `cellWidth` is set from the parent in the beginning.

So the solution depends on what you want to achieve. One possibility is to provide a function which executes/tries again after a short timeout if the variable is not yet initialized, or your use a reactive statement, which will execute after every change to that variable (probably the better option).

```svelte
<script>
  import { afterUpdate } from "svelte";

  export let cellWidth;

  // Option 1
  function logCellWidth() {
    if (cellWidth === undefined) {
      setTimeout(() => logCellWidth(), 100);
    } else {
      console.log('cellWidth1', cellWidth);
    }
  }

  afterUpdate(logCellWidth);

  // Option 2
  $: cellWidth !== undefined && console.log('cellWidth2', cellWidth);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it is only available afterwards (if you start resizing after the initial 2 undefineds it should show up)

An alternative approach that does seem to get the correct value immediately is to use a reactive statement:

```
$: console.log(cellWidth)
```